# Browse for file in VBA and have data placed in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to open up a file browser in VBA, select a text file and have the data placed in an excel spreadsheet so that the data can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Friendly reminder since you seem to be new, it's preferred that you show what you have already tried (by pasting the code within the question).

Below is code that I use to pull data from a text file. Since your question is pretty broad, I'm assuming that you're like me and the text file is a csv has one line per item, that there's a unique value within that line and you want a piece of information from that line. (Kinda like how we use vlookup or index/match.)

It requires using the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (which is found in the VBA Editor under Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime) because it uses a dictionary.

```
Static oFS
Static oFSO As FileSystemObject
Static dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim MySplit() As String
Dim sText As String
Dim message As String

If dict Is Nothing Then
    Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("[Address to text file]")

    Do Until oFS.AtEndOfStream
        sText = oFS.ReadLine
        MySplit = Split(sText, ",")                 ' This is for comma delimited files
        'MySplit = Split(sText, Chr(9))             ' This is for Tab delimited files
        If Not dict.Exists(MySplit(x)) Then
            dict.Add MySplit(x), MySplit(y)
        End If
    Loop
    If dict.Exists(UCase(Legacy)) Then
        ' Code here to put data into spreadsheet
    Else
        MsgBox "Data not found"
    End If
Else
    If dict.Exists(UCase(Legacy)) Then
        ' Code here to put data into spreadsheet
    Else
        MsgBox "Data not found"
    End If
End If
```

For me this is a function that has one argument (Legacy) which could be a cell that your function checks. And MySplit(x) is going to be the dictionary key and the lookup value. MySplit(y) is the dictionary item and could be the data getting pulled; where x and y are indices of any given line. i.e. I have a text file with the line:

```
12345, 15, Blue
67890, 20, Red
54321, 30, Green
```

I want to lookup "12345" and pull "Blue" so MySplit(x) will become MySplit(0) and MySplit(y) will become MySplit(2). HTH